# How to change the click event to the hover in Slick?

Tags: jquery

This works properly by clicking. I want to change the click event to the hover. Now when I click on the title the image changes well but I want to change the image by hovering not clicking :please have a look at the image
[image]

```
$('.slider').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: true,
      fade: true,
      autoplay: true,
      asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
     });


     $('.slider-nav').slick({
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      asNavFor: '.slider',
      dots: true,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      vertical:true
     });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32907070/1982680 may help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slick Slider binding hover event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906434/slick-slider-binding-hover-event)

Comment: I have used this code but did not work !